# Ubuntu Installation from Windows

Tags: installation, iso

I have downloaded ubuntu desktop from the ubuntu website and name of the file is  "ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso" as i am running from an intel machine.

That ISO file i have mounted using power iso and now i am trying to install from it using .exe file for ubuntu installer.

Still i am getting an error 
Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO.

If once i have already downloaded ISO,why would i need to download it again.

Please someone help me to solve this.

I have got something more.

If anyone can help me with this...... This time ubuntu installer tried to download the file ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

why this file on an intel machine

Comment: The workarounds presented in [Ubuntu Wubi install is freezing / stalling / hanging on iso download](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520677/ubuntu-wubi-install-is-freezing-stalling-hanging-on-iso-download), including downloading and verifying the ISO yourself and invoking `wubi.exe` with the `--skipmd5check` flag, may help.

Answer (score 0):

use the WUBI installer to install Ubuntu thru Windows 8 there is an excellent guide at this link
http://apcmag.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-linux.htm
then get the WUBi installer at UBUNTU
and double click and follow the instructions
you might also consider AOMEI as partitioner and partition a separate drive for WUBI to install on

Comment: i tried to install it in a USB drive

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found to be the problem:
The installation executable is looking for an ISO file to install. Since the ISO is mounted you will need to copy that installation .exe into the same directory as your ISO file.

For example, if your ISO is in E:\ubuntu.iso
and if your mounted ISO file is in D:\
your installer should be D:\wubi.exe

Then you will need to copy wubi.exe to E:\wubi.exe, placing it next to the ubuntu.iso file. Unmount your ISO image, and then run wubi.exe as Administrator. This should allow you to install.

Pictures can be found here:
http://tech.nickballesteros.com/2011/05/ubuntu-error-cannot-download-metalink.html

Comment: tried got the same error