# Wubi - Download stops when in middle of download

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, wubi

I'm trying to download Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using Wubi from the official site of Ubuntu. But in the middle, it just stop downloading but still responsive but doesn't make any progress.

since I can't find solution on the Internet I close it, and now it wants to uninstall the previous installation progress

Is there a way to resume what I already download?
or can I download Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in torrent and link it in wubi?

Answer (score 1):

I [had the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520677/ubuntu-wubi-install-is-freezing-stalling-hanging-on-iso-download) and got a great answer. You can download the iso file with a torrent client or your browser or a download manager. Then do your own MD5/SHA-1 check using [Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533). Put the iso file in the same directory as wubi.exe and it will use that instead of trying to download. Unfortunately there is [another bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1080964) that prevents it from successfully checking the MD5 sum. So you have to open a Windows command prompt and type wubi --skipmd5check.

For me that got the install to go, however I personally ran into what I think is another bug. The install says (on both of two attempts) that "Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /".  There is [forum discussion on this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218439) and even a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIKf_uM9FHI) on how to fix it and says that "This happens when you use the Wubi installation method with Ubuntu 14".

Answer (score -1):

Wubi is no longer an option of installing Ubuntu. Anything after WinXP is going to create issues for you. It is much better to boot from USB Drive or create a bootable DVD. Download the actual Ubuntu Software from the home website (Ubuntu.com/desktop (avoid WUBI)). If you have done either of these 2, just reboot and hit F12, change the boot order to USB or DVD and off you go. Much simpler to just install it yourself.

Comment: You may want to expand this to explain why you think Wubi works less well on Windows Vista or 7 than it does on Windows XP. (For a Windows 8/1.8 system that came preinstalled, it's always on a GPT disk on a UEFI machine, and Wubi will not be able to create a usable system under those conditions. But even with Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 installed by the user on a machine that didn't ship with it, Wubi should work as well as it does on previous Windows OSes. See [this post by bcbc](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168608/how-to-boot-wubi-installed-ubuntu-within-windows-8/225082#225082) for details.)

Answer (score -1):

Just Get A USB (2GB minimum), Download the ubuntu iso image

For Direct Download use http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

For The Torrent Download Visit http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads scroll down and you will see the torrent links

Use UnetBootin to install the iso image you downloaded into the usb drive

Restart your computer select boot from usb from the BIOS Menu it should boot from the usb drive. The ubuntu installation should guide you from there

Comment: While I agree doing a standard installation *alongside* instead of *inside* Windows, as you've described, is likely the best thing to do here, it's important to note that this will *not* create a Wubi system, this will resize the Windows partition, and so forth.