# wubi compares 14.04 md5sum with md5sum from 14.04.1 file

Tags: 14.04, wubi, md5sum

I downloaded lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.  The calculated md5sum is: 281fc36d625f7ca0704297b3b811fa66 .  According to help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes that is the correct md5sum.  Also according to cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/lubuntu-**14.04.1**-desktop-i386.metalink that is the correct md5sum.  But wubi downloads instead .../14.04/release/lubuntu-**14.04**-desktop-i386.metalink, that is the 14.04 version with a different md5sum

Here is the wubi.log showing this:

```
09-12 12:01 INFO   Distro: Found a valid iso for Lubuntu: F:\lubuntu-14.04.1->desktop-i386.iso
09-12 12:01 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_metalink
09-12 12:01 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_metalink...
09-12 12:01 DEBUG  downloader: downloading .../lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-**14.04**-desktop-i386.metalink > C:\ubuntu\install
...
09-12 12:01 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 1043 bytes)
...

09-12 12:01 ERROR  CommonBackend: The md5 of the metalink does match
09-12 12:01 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot authenticate the metalink file, it might be corrupt
None
09-12 12:01 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_metalink
09-12 12:01 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_file_md5
09-12 12:01 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_file_md5...
09-12 12:02 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_file_md5
09-12 12:02 ERROR  CommonBackend: Invalid md5 for ISO F:\lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop->i386.iso (b0d1c58c8515ab40382d01f59655ba85 != 281fc36d625f7ca0704297b3b811fa66)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Well, you could try planting the 14.04 image there before running Wubi.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu Wubi install is freezing / stalling / hanging on iso download](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520677/ubuntu-wubi-install-is-freezing-stalling-hanging-on-iso-download) (You can run `wubi.exe` with the `--skipmd5check` flag.)

Comment: Instead of 'planting the 14.04 image before' I could also wubi let it download, but unfortunately that takes 29 hours.

Comment: But using --skipmd5check works, but actually wubi shouldn't compare the md5sum of the 14.04.1 file with the md5sum published for the 14.04 file in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Eliah Kagan's solution works fine. A bit more detail for real beginners:

1. Copy Wubi to the hard disk from the CD. If you do not do it, Wubi just launches the CD install.
2. Open a command window:

   #### Option A

   - Go to the Windows Start button, click and write `cmd` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   - Then you need to change directory to the one containing `wubi.exe`.

   #### Option B

   - Open an explorer window and navigate to the folder containing `wubi.exe`.
   - Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-click the folder icon.
   - From the popup menu, select *Open window command window here*.
3. Execute wubi disabling MD5 check. Write `wubi --skipmd5check`.

Follow the on-screen instructions to install a Wubi system.